# Geting SelectList to MVC view using AJAX/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a C# MVC application which is populating a dropdown based on a date selected. Once the date is selected I am sending it to an action via AJAX/jQuery. The action gets a list of items to return for that date.

Here is where my problem is. I have done it previously where I render a partial view from the action and pass it the SelectList as the model. However, I really just want to do it inline in the original view, so I'm hoping there is some way I can return the SelectList and from there do some magic Javascript/JQuery to put it into a dropdown.

Has anybody ever done this before? If so, what do I on the client end after calling the load() to return the SelectList?

I've done something like this previously, when I was just returning a string or other value to be rendered as straight text:

```
$("#returnTripRow").load("/Trip.aspx/GetTripsForGivenDate?date=" + escape(selection));
```

But I'm not sure how to intercept the data and morph it into am Html.DropDown() call, or equivalent.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Supposing you have a controller action that will feed the data for the dropdown:

```
public ActionResult Cars()
{
    return Json(new[] {
        new { id = "bmw", name = "BMW" },
        new { id = "mer", name = "Mercedes" },
        new { id = "aud", name = "Audi" }
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And in your view:

```
$.getJSON('/home/cars', { }, function(cars) {
    var list = $('select#cars');
    list.find('option').remove();
    $(cars).each(function(index, car) {
        list.append('<option value="' + car.id + '">' + car.name + '</option>');
    });
});
```